# COZIGAM error Error in magic... L must be a matrix

Tags: r

I try to use COZIGAM package to fit a zero inflated regression model. Both on my data set and the real example data set that comes with the package I get this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'catch' not found, although I load the data and I specify the data set in the model:

> data(eggdata)
>
> egg.res <- cozigam(catch ~ s(lon,lat) + s(log(bottom)), log.tran = TRUE, family = gaussian, data = eggdata) Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'catch' not found.

I tried attach(eggdata), even if I know that it is not recommended and the new error is this:

> attach(eggdata)
>
> egg.res <- cozigam(catch ~ s(lon,lat) + s(log(bottom)), log.tran = TRUE, family = gaussian, data = eggdata) Error in magic(y.c, X.c, G1$sp, G1$S, G1$off, G1$rank, C = G1$C, w = w.c,  :    L must be a matrix.

Did anyone have the same issue. Any suggestion what should I do. Thank you!

Comment: COZIGAM is no longer on CRAN and the latest version in the archives seems to be from 2012. What version of R and COZIGAM are you running?

Comment: I could not install the package on R 3.2.1, the version I usually use, so I installed R version 2.9.2 (2009.08.24) and the COZIGAM package is COZIGAM_1.0-1.zip.

Comment: I found a solution! It is much easier to use package mgcv with the function ziP() to fit a Gam zero inflated Poisson regression.